# How do you loop through the elements of the object returned by the Python 3 set() method?

Tags: python-3.x, set

I am creating a set of unique elements using the Python 3 set() method, and am wondering how to loop through the returned object.

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate through your set:

```
s = set('aabcdd')

for _ in s:
     ...
```

Or, you can create a list from your set:

```
s = set('aabcdd')
l = list(s)

for _ in l:
  ...
```

Comment: There's no need to `list` it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the `set()` method in **Python 3** returns an un-ordered collection of unique elements, for example `set('bbabc')` returns `{'b', 'a', 'c'}`.

Let's say you have a set defined as such - `new_set = set('bbabc')`. You can loop through this collection like so:

```
for element in new_set: 
     ....
```